# React.js Error: An AuthUI instance already exists for the key "[DEFAULT]"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am able to render Firebase Auth UI widget when I keep all the code in the top level App.js file. But when I move the UI code into a component it suddenly shows: `Error: An AuthUI instance already exists for the key "[DEFAULT]"`

As far as I can tell, there has only been one instance of AuthUI.

Here is the relevant code in App.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';

// FIREBASE SERVICES: Additional services that you want to use
// require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");
require("firebase/firestore");
require("firebase/messaging");
require("firebase/functions");


export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };


    componentDidMount() {

        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "<removed>",
            authDomain: "<removed>",
            databaseURL: "<removed>",
            projectId: "<removed>",
            storageBucket: "<removed>",
            messagingSenderId: "<removed>"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Here is the code moved into a Login component:

```
import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";
import firebase from "firebase";

require("firebase/auth");


// FirebaseUI config.
const uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '#create-account', // the root of the URL is auto-appended
    signInOptions: [
        // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        // firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        // firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        // firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
    // Privacy policy url.
    privacyPolicyUrl: '<your-privacy-policy-url>'
};

export const LoginOptions = (props) => {

    // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
    const firebase_ui_widget = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

    // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
    firebase_ui_widget.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" style={{ marginTop : '5vh'}}></div>
```

When a state value causes the component to render, the page immediately breaks with the error in the title.

Can anyone spot the issue?

I should also mention that I get a 2nd error at the same time as the 1st:

```
Error: Could not find the FirebaseUI widget element on the page.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
LoginOptions
src/components/LoginOptions.js:39
  36 | const firebase_ui_widget = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  37 | 
  38 | // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
> 39 | firebase_ui_widget.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
  40 | 
  41 | return (
  42 | <React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `const firebase_ui_widget = ...; firebase_ui_widget.start(...);` outside of a components render method, like e.g. in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Yes, it was outside class App when I did most of my testing. When I started getting these errors I moved it into componentDidMount(). It did not appear to help.

Comment: Can that component be dismounted/mounted again? That is probably why the `AuthUI` code is run more than once.

Comment: I don't think so. Does App.js ever dismount? I thought it persists through the life of the app. And I get this same exact error when the code in App.js is outside the class. You are making me ponder how this might apply to LoginOptions though (the child that has the UI code)

Comment: Yes, your topmost component will persist throughout the life of the app, but you are creating a new `AuthUI` on every component render, which happens on every state of props update. But `LoginOptions` is not your topmost component either right?

Comment: Right, LoginOptions is a child (2 levels down. MainArea is it's immediate parent)

Comment: Great. Calling `AuthUI` in `LoginOptions`'s `componentDidMount` instead of `render` is probably the way forward, granted that `LoginOptions` is never unmounted and mounted again, because then you would get the same issue again.